# What effects does Orisa's Fortify resist?

Tags: overwatch

Jeff Kaplan mentioned that Orisa's Fortify ability will resist some crowd control effects, such as Pharah's concussive blast. The gameplay video for Orisa on playoverwatch.com also shows her resisting a Reinhardt Earthshatter.

So, what other effects does it resist? Does it stop things like Roadhog's hook, or stop her from getting affected by Zarya's ultimate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/5x5b9y/orisa_blocks_any_and_all_cc_with_her_fortify/defdvjb/), Orisa's Fortify resists the following effects:

- McCree's Flashbang
- Pharah's Concussive Blast
- Junkrat's Concussion Mine
- Junkrat's Steel Trap
- Mei's Endothermic Blaster
- Mei's Blizzard
- D.Va's Boost
- Orisa's Halt!
- Reinhardt's Charge
- Reinhardt's Earthshatter
- Roadhog's Hook
- Ana's Sleep Dart
- Lucio's Soundwave

After additional testing, Fortify also resists the following crowd control effects:

- Soldier: 76's Helix Rockets (they have a very small knockback effect)
- Roadhog's Whole Hog
- Winston's Primal Rage
- Zarya's Particle Cannon alternate fire
- Zarya's Graviton Surge
- Symmetra's Sentry Turrets
- Bastion's Configuration: Tank

Comment: I'm not sure why Zenyatta's Discord is in this list as it's not an action-impairing effect.

Comment: That's a great answer and I'd rather you add to it than I simply link to the following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFkSCDPLkZQ they seam to mention the non-tested effects too.

Comment: @Powerlord See the "crowd control effects to be tested" bit.

Comment: Can you use fortify to break out of stuns or does it have to be used ahead of time.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill You can't do anything while stunned.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Yes, I was commenting on why it was in that section.  Discord Orb isn't a crowd control effect... or more importantly, an action-impairing effect which is how the Fortify ability is actually worded.

Comment: @Powerlord Answer has been edited to suite your question; it does not in fact resist Discord.